# Verilog, can i assign a bit value to multiple bits inside always block

Tags: verilog

Below is the code:

```
always @ (C[n-1])
begin
   C[2*n-1:n]=C[n-1];
end
```

Is that possible? If not, how can I do it? Basically it's performing a sign extension.

Comment: another question, how to put indentation here?

Comment: You can select code and hit the "indent code" button which creates a multi-line code block by indenting it 4 spaces.  Indenting beyond 4 spaces will then indent the code.

Comment: If you declare a signal as signed, or use $signed(), Verilog will sign-extend on assignment for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for replicating a bit in Verilog is `{COUNT{bits}}`.  In your case something like `{n{C[n-1]}}`